# Clarification of a statement in the context of not needing an intersection axiom in ZFC set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would appreciate clarification of my misunderstanding of the highlighted statement below, which defines a set by separation. It is  part of a note that an intersection axiom is unnecessary in ZFC set theory:

> > If $S$ is a non-empty set and $x_0$ is an element in $S$, then
> >     $$\bigcap_{x\in S} x= \{y\in x_0:y\in x \text{ for all } x\in S\}$$

Where I am confused is: what if there are some $y$'s in every $x\in S$ but are not in $x_0$, how will they be included in the intersection?

Thanks

Comment: What you wrote is notationally incoherent: $\bigcap_{x\in S}$ by itself does not mean anything. I suspect you meant to write $\bigcap_{x\in S}x$, which, more succinctly, can also be written as $\bigcap S$.

Comment: A typo of omission; fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x_0\in S$, if $y\in x$ for all $x\in S$, then $y\in x_0$.